# Speaker recognition, max total input length for enrollment

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

The Azure Speaker Recognition  V2 API specifies the maximum input length for Text independent enrollment is 300s and that it should raise a 403 error if it exceeds this.

I've currently got profiles with the enrollmentsSpeachLength and enrollmentsLength in the profile greater than 300s.
Is this out dated documentation? Has the max length increased?  What currently happens when the 300s limit is exceeded, does it keep enrolling the audio or ignore it?

sample responses...
using file  Andy_textindependantmisssi.wav (12 seconds,mono 16kHz)
we get....

{"remainingEnrollmentsSpeechLength":0.0,"profileId":"xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx","enrollmentStatus":"Enrolled","enrollmentsCount":22,"enrollmentsLength":417.51,"enrollmentsSpeechLength":363.4,"audioLength":12.33,"audioSpeechLength":8.67}

Retry using the same file...

{"remainingEnrollmentsSpeechLength":0.0,"profileId":"xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx","enrollmentStatus":"Enrolled","enrollmentsCount":23,"enrollmentsLength":429.84,"enrollmentsSpeechLength":372.07,"audioLength":12.33,"audioSpeechLength":8.67}

Retry with a shorter file (myvoiceismypassport) file...(2.4seconds)

{"remainingEnrollmentsSpeechLength":0.0,"profileId":"xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx","enrollmentStatus":"Enrolled","enrollmentsCount":24,"enrollmentsLength":432.8,"enrollmentsSpeechLength":374.81,"audioLength":2.96,"audioSpeechLength":2.74}

Comment: Can you please share the audio that you are trying?

Comment: Also please share the API response.

Comment: added some responses returned by the API

Comment: https://filebin.net/n67ody2ew02mkjyd for sample of audio file

Comment: @Ram-msft is there any progress with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting !

This is a known issue and has been flagged already. The fix for the observed behavior is scheduled in the first week of December (Tentative).

Having said that **300 seconds** is the correct number for Maximum Enrollments Length as per the documentation (the  mentioned fix should prevent this in the future).

Apologies for the inconvenience.